# Should I bother adding a class on a <main> tag?

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

Should I bother adding a class on a `<main>` tag?

I try to avoid poor selector Intent like  `header {}` to avoid risk of applying very specific styling to a very wide number of elements in my project, but according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main):

> There must not be more than one `<main>` element in a document

So I wonder, if I use a simple selector like `main {}`, would this still be considered a bad practice?

Comment: If you're going to adhere to the standard and only have one `main` element in your projects, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @IanHunter, this seems logic, but I still wonder if this won't comes back and bites me in the ass later on.

Comment: WHATWG HTML allows several `main` elements. Whether WHATWG HTML or W3C HTML5 is "HTML standard" is a matter of opinion, and the use of classes is a matter of opinion or coding style,

Answer (score 1):

well, while I understand your premise, my answer is yes without a doubt. I use it a lot, and I develop custom WP sites and templates, so I add classes to main element in order to have only a stylesheet, then I can target the main element for different templates from the same stylesheet or re-using declarations with minimal changes. For example: main element on index page will usually differ from main element's content on inner pages, archives, search pages, etc, specially on highly customized sites

Of course, if that's not your case, then there's no need and it's probably better to leave it without a class, but this goes also in taste. I tend to build my themes with classes, no matter if unused. This way, if a client or user needs to use that element at a later time, is easier to do it.

Needless to say, from a semantic point of view:

```
<main class="index">
<main class="page">
<main class="archive">
<main class="blog">
```

looks a lot better than just `<main>`

All this being said, it depends on your and your workflow, it's not set in stone, like many HTML5 and W3C recommendations